# log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig

Tags: java, log4j, mybatis

In my java web application I used Mybatis for mapping and I have log4j library. Before few minutes I didn't have this problem, I don't know what happened, please help me.

```
Grave: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory).
Grave: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Grave: log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```